# A question about prime gaps

Tags: number-theory, functions, prime-numbers, asymptotics, prime-gaps

I have been reading the Wikipedia article about prime gaps (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) and I came across the following:

> Hoheisel was the first to show that there exists a constant $\theta<1$ such that $$\pi(x+x^\theta)-\pi(x)\sim\frac{x^\theta}{\log x}$$ as $x$ tends to infinity.

I have a few questions:

1. What's the meaning of the $\sim$ symbol?
2. Does the symbol $\sim$ mean that $\pi(x+x^\theta)-\pi(x)$ is asymptotic to $x^\theta/\log x$? If this is the case, does this mean that $\pi(x+x^\theta)-\pi(x)$ is always greater than $x^\theta/\log x$ at least for sufficiently large $x$? Is $\pi(x+x^\theta)-\pi(x)$ the same as $\pi[x,x+x^\theta]$, that is to say, the amount of primes in the interval $[x,x+x^\theta]$?

I'm not sure what the above expression means, and I'm not sure what it means when they say that a certain function is "asymptotic" to another function or when they say that a certain asymptotic formula holds.

3. Also, in the above expression, is $\log$ the natural logarithm or the logarithm in base $10$?

Comment: $\sim$ means asymptotic equality, so $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (\pi(x+x^\theta)-\pi(x))\frac{\log x}{x^\theta} = 1.$$ And $\log$ is the natural logarithm.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But does this mean that $\pi(x+x^\theta)-\pi(x)$ is always greater than $x^\theta/\log x$? And is $\pi(x+x^\theta)-\pi(x)$ the same as $\pi[x,x+x^\theta]$?

Comment: No, it need not always be greater. It cannot be too much smaller in the long run, however. If $\pi[x,x+x^\theta]$ means the number of primes between $x$ and $x+x^\theta$, then it means the same as $\pi(x+x^\theta)-\pi(x)$.

Comment: I think I'm kind of confused and maybe I'm mixing up things. For example, if consider the function $f(x)=1/x$, then its asymptotes are the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis. If consider the positive values for $x$, then as $x$ increases $f(x)=1/x$ gets smaller and smaller but never reaches $0$ (the graph of the function never touches the $x$-axis). This is why I thought that if a function $f(x)$ was asymptotic to another function $g(x)$, then $f(x)$ was always greater than $g(x)$ (or the other way round). What can I do to correctly understand this specific topic? I'm confused.

Comment: $f \sim g$ means $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1.$$ That is something different from (but not entirely unrelated to) the asymptotes of functions like the axes for $1/x$.

Comment: Thank your for your comments. So this means that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\pi(x+x^\theta)-\pi(x)}{x^\theta/\log x}=1$$ as you told me. According to the Wikipedia article Baker, Harman and Pintz showed in 2001 that $\theta$ may be taken to be $0.525$. So how does the fact that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\pi(x+x^{0.525})-\pi(x)}{x^{0.525}/\log x}=1$$ imply that there is always a prime in the interval $[x,x+x^{0.525}]$ for sufficiently large $x$?

Comment: The denominator $x^\theta/\log x$ grows towards infinity. Since the quotient tends to $1$, it follows that $\pi(x+x^\theta) - \pi(x)$, the number of primes in the interval $(x,x+x^\theta]$ grows towards infinity too. In particular, it can be $0$ only up to a certain point.

Comment: Thank your for your help!!

Comment: I'm sorry, I have one more question. So, as you told me, the denominator $x^\theta/\log x$ grows towards infinity, and the quotient, which tends to $1$, can be $0$ only up to a certain point. But, after that certain point, can't the quotient still be $0$ sometimes and still tend to $1$? Or is the quotient continuously getting closer and closer to $1$ without ever "going down" again?

Comment: It can drop a little, so the convergence need not be (is not, actually) monotonic. The quotient tending to $1$ means for every $0 < \varepsilon < 1$, there is an $x_\varepsilon$ such that $$1-\varepsilon < \frac{\pi(x+x^\theta)-\pi(x)}{x^\theta/\log x} < 1+\varepsilon$$ for all $x \geqslant x_\varepsilon$. So after $x_\varepsilon$, the quotient cannot oscillate by more than $2\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)\sim g(x)$ just means that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/g(x)=1.$ Informally, $g(x)$ is a good approximation for $f(x)$ (and vice versa) when $x$ is large.

$\pi(x+x^\theta)-\pi(x)\sim x^\theta/\log x$ mean that

1. $\pi(x+x^\theta)-\pi(x)$ is greater than $0.99x^\theta/\log x$ for sufficiently large $x$ , and this would remain true (for a different value of "large  enough") if you replace 0.99 with any number less than 1.
2. $\pi(x+x^\theta)-\pi(x)$ is less than $1.01x^\theta/\log x$ for sufficiently large $x$, and this would remain true (for a different value of "large  enough") if you replace 1.01 with any number greater than 1.

And yes, $\log$ is the natural logarithm, and $\pi(x+x^\theta)-\pi(x)$ is the number of primes in the interval $(x,x+x^\theta]$.